# Adding sliders to a Streamlit app to adjust model inputs

Tags: pandas, dataframe, streamlit

Hi I am trying to create sliders for adjusting the values of a model using a dictionary.
The dataframe contains multiple columns of floats.
The index column are unique city names that are used to select a slice of the data.
The column names and index are object type.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['London', 'Bedford'], 'Value_1': [0.256, 0.425], 'Value_2': [0.859, 0.956]})
df = df.set_index('city')

def display_sliders():
        sliders = {}
        for col in df.columns:
            min_val = df[col].min()
            max_val = df[col].max()
            val = df[col].loc[selected_city]
            sliders[col] = st.slider(col, min_value=min_val, max_value=max_val, value=val)
        return sliders

# Display the slider widgets
sliders = display_sliders()
```

When I run the code it returns an error:

```
KeyError: <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

The error points to the line:

```
sliders[col] = st.slider(col, min_value=min_val, max_value=max_val, value=val
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of head scratching I found the answer thanks to mathscatsand Streamlit moderator:

The solution is too cast the values as floats on the following line:

```
sliders[col] = st.slider(col, min_value=float(min_val), max_value=float(max_val), value=float(val))
```

Comment: The reason this error occurs is because the values are numpy.float64 and they need to be just python floats. By casting them directly it ensures they are python floats.